# kendoMultiSelect: Java Selenium How to select multiple values?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

I am trying to select multiple values from a kendoMultiSelect, I can't interact it with the Selenium methods. I guess i need to use javascript execute function. What function should i use?

Answer (score 1):

Yes javascript execute function will be your safest bet.

To use it in selenium you need to use the `JavascriptExecutor` interface of a driver.

```
// Use your existing driver here
WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();  
//JavascriptExecutor interface object by casting    
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
//executeAsyncScript() method with your JS      
js.executeAsyncScript("kendoMultiSelect.value(["Value 1","Value 2"]);");
```

The `kendoMultiSelect` variable is a JS variable that references your instance of the select.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to use it like this;                                          JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) getDriver();
        String target1="11:18:44.021098800";
        String target2="11:20:28.625521400";
        js.executeAsyncScript("kendoMultiSelect.value(["target1","target2"]);");                             But the compiler does not accept these lines. I am getting 'semicolon expected' errors.

Comment: ```js.executeAsyncScript("kendoMultiSelect.value([" + target1 + "," + target2 + "]);");``` missing plus signs on the string concatenation